# Mock File.createTempFile() and return our mocked File object

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, powermockito, powermockrunner

How can we mock `File.createTempFile()` to return our mocked File object?

It should return our mocked file object instead of creating a new temp file and return new object.

Comment: Mock a RandomAccessFile with Mockito?

Comment: can you please elaborate it?

Comment: It is not possible to mock static methods with Mockito. Either use powermockito or introduce indirection in your code

Comment: Yeah. I mean powermockito

Comment: @Lesiak can I am using powermockito only. Can to tell me how we can do it?

Comment: can you put the class and method which u want to test, also the test code which you have written so far

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(File.class);
 File mockFile =  PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
 when(File.createTempFile(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockFile);
```

cannot suggest more without the code or test class

Comment: I am running into problems with this because it ends up calling File.createTempFile("","") which throws an exception because the prefix is too short.  I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Same experience. Do you find the answer?

Comment: Annotate the test class with: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ File.class })